# Core plot. Lables overlapped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-plot

Hi I have a core plot graphic. By default it looks fine, but if I resize it, lables on x axis are overlapped. 
I have dates on x axis, how can I change days to weeks? please see screenshot.
Is it some event which heppen on resize?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default axis labeling policy puts the ticks a constant distance apart. You might try the `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` labeling policy. This policy will automatically adjust the tick spacing as the plot range changes.

Comment: thanks. It works for me. http://yaplex.com/iphone-core-plot-plotting-framework-lables-overlapped-53/